# Newtonsoft Json.Net correct parsing of string arrays inside a JSON object

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json.net

I have the following problem, I want to parse a Json object I get passed by a url query string

e.g.

```
...&json={tags=[tag1,tag2]}
```

I have used

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json)
```

But when calling the Deserialize method I get an error

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: d. Line 1, position 8.
```

If I pass in the string

```
"{tags:[\"tag1\",\"tag2\"]}
```

It works fine, I don't want my users to have to add the "" quotes

Is there a way to work around this problem?

Comment: What is the value of the json string at the point it reaches your application? It may be URLEncoded

Comment: either your users have to send you valid json or you have to convert from DavidMZSpecialNameToStringAlmostLikeJason to real json then the serializer will be able parse it.... or you could write your own deserialization code.

Comment: "{tags=[tag1,tag2]}" is no valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode For a solution could be...

Grab the json query string element.

Split on first equals "=".

Grab all text between "{tags=[" and "]}"

Take that text split on ","

trim any whitespace off of the items.

Join them back together but put quotes around them and coma delimited them.

put that value back inbetween "{tags=[" and "]}"   ie "{tags=[" + newValue+ "]}"

Here is some sample C# code...

```
        [Test]
        public void TestHack()
        {
            string almost = "{tags=[tag1,tag2]}";
            string json = this.HackToJson(almost);
            Trace.WriteLine(json);
        }
        public string HackToJson(string almostJson)
        {
            if( almostJson.StartsWith("{tags=[") && almostJson.EndsWith("]}"))
            {
                int tagsLen = "{tags=[".Length;
                string tags = almostJson.Substring(tagsLen, almostJson.Length - (tagsLen + 2));

                var items = tags.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                var itemsCleaned = (from c in items select "\"" + c.Trim() + "\"");

                var jsonpart = string.Join(",", itemsCleaned);

                var json = string.Format("{{tags=[{0}]}}", jsonpart);

                return json;

            }
            throw new NotImplementedException("not sure what to do here... ");
        }
```